# Fuse-Box,VSCode,React,Typescript and debugging

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, source-maps

I have issue in my VSCode (1.24.0) with Debugger for Chrome extensions(4.5.0) and debugging react application bundling over fuse-box bundler.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

fuse.ts:

```
import { FuseBox, WebIndexPlugin, CSSPlugin } from "fuse-box";
import { task } from "fuse-box/sparky";
import path from "path";

const isProduction = false;

task("default", async () => {
  const fuse = FuseBox.init({
    homeDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    output: "public/$name.js",
    target: "browser",
    log: true,
    sourceMaps: { vendor: false },
    tsConfig: "tsconfig.json",
    plugins: [
      CSSPlugin(),
      WebIndexPlugin({
        template: "src/index.html",
        appendBundles: true
      })
    ]
  });

  if (!isProduction) {
    fuse.dev({ port: 4545 });
  }

  const bundle = fuse
    .bundle("app")
    .target("browser")
    .instructions("> index.tsx");

  if (!isProduction) {
    bundle.watch("src**").hmr();
  }

  await fuse.run();
});
```

package.json

```
"ts-node": "^6.1.0",
"typescript": "^2.9.1"
"fuse-box": "^3.2.2",
```

scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node -r ts-node/register ./fuse.ts"
   }
```

My folders structure is:

```
public/index.html
public/app.js
public/app.js.ap

src/index.html
src/index.tsx
src/Sidebar.tsx
...

./fuse.ts
./tsconfig.json
./package.json
```

And finally my launch.json:

```
  ....
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "debug-client",
  "url": "http://localhost:4545",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "/*": "${webRoot}/*"
  }
```

And question is simple, when i run debug from vscode, chrome starts, application starts too, but vscode returns issue breakpoint (breakpoint is grey).

.scripts(debug console)returns right path and debug works in browser.

What am I missing?

Thanks